# MVC View nullable Date field formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, razor

I am trying to display the following in a view but is giving a problem:

```
    <td>
     @item.CreatedByDt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") 
    </td>
```

Any idea on how to handle a nullable Date field in a view. I am using Razor by the way.

I am getting the following error:

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you don't know if it will be null or not...

```
@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item.CreatedByDt)
```

Comment: if I use like that in webgrid, I got this error
**Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: args **

Comment: This will give error if used on nullable DateTime with NULL value

Answer (score 12):

```
@(item.CreatedByDt.HasValue ? item.CreatedByDt.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "--/--/----")
```

You can replace the display string for when your date is null with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@item.CreatedByDt.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Will through an exception if it is null

Answer (score 0):

If `DateTime?` is a null value, they give an error.

This solution will not generate an error:

```
@functions{
    string FormatNullableDate(DateTime? value) => value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "-";
}

<td>
@FormatNullableDateTime(item.CreatedByDt)
</td>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@item.PostDatePublished.Value.ToString
```

need the value in there

Comment: Will through an exception if it is null