# Cannot Bind Null Value: WebGrid nullable Date field

Tags: jquery, webgrid, asp.net-webpages

I am getting this error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot perform
> runtime binding on a null reference

When I try to include nullable DateTime fields in my WebGrid and cannot find any workarounds.  I have DateTime values that may always be null, and this is by design.  Here is the grid column that offends:

```
MeetingDetailsGrid.Column(header: "Date", 
format: @<span>
<span id="spanDateOpen_@item.ID">@item.DateOpen.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")</span>
@Html.TextBox("miDateOpen_"+(int)item.ID,(string)item.DateOpen.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM"), new {@type = "date", @style = "display:none"})
 THIS NEXT LINE GIVES THE EXCEPTION
<span id="spanDateClosed_@item.ID">@(item.DateClosed!=null ? item.DateClosed.Value.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") : " ")</span></span>) <--this line
```

The open date will always have a value, as for a new item it is set to `DateTime.Today` but the closed date can remain null and this webgrid is extended to allow for setting that date in the future.  I have seen some examples with the inline if else so I have added that: `@(item.DateClosed!=null ? item.DateClosed.Value.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") : ""` (I want the string formatting as well) here when the value is not null.  But this gives the same exception.

Using `item.DateClosed.HasValue()` in the inline if else macro also yields the error.  This is all occurring in the WebGrid.GetHtml( . . . grid.Column) portion of my partial Razor view.

I also found a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331902/mvc-view-nullable-date-field-formatting) to add a function to call to check the value and return an empty string if it is null:

```
@functions{
string FormatNullableDate(DateTime? value) => value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "-";
}
```

And tried to use it like so, and still get the error:

```
<span id="spanDateClosed_@item.ID">@FormatNullableDate(item.DateClosed)</span>
```

The only way I can get it to work is by putting my `@if()` logic like this:

```
<span id="spanDateClosed@item.ID">@if(item.DateClosed != null) {item.DateCLosed;}</span>
```

But this way the user cannot enter a close date easily (I would need to provide another button or something to hit to then enter a close date).  Is there really no way to bind a nullable field to a grid when the value is null?  I think this will work if the first item in the collection had a proper closed date, but that will definitely not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what about the the client server separation makes me forget the basics, but this is a simple matter of extending the model to include a string parameter to get the date value:

```
public string sDateClosed
{
    get { return DateClosed.HasValue ? DateClosed.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty; }
    set { DateClosed = DateTime.Parse(value); }
}
```

I created a partial class file for the model class and added a parameter that returns the nullable field as a string value.  Bind this parameter to the view and everything works.